# javascript regex, split user's full name

Tags: javascript, regex

I have user's firstname and lastname in one string, with space between
e.g.
`John Doe`
`Peter Smithon`

And now I want convert this string to two string - firstname and lastname
`John Doe` -> first = `John`, last = `Doe`
`John` -> first = `John`, last = ""
`[space]Doe` -> first = "", last = `Doe`.

I am using next code

```
var fullname = "john Doe"
var last = fullname.replace(/^.*\s/, "").toUpperCase().trim(); // john
var first = fullname.replace(/\s.*$/, "").toUpperCase().trim(); // Doe
```

and this works well for two-word fullname. But if fullname has one word, then I have problem

```
var fullname = "john"  
var last = fullname.replace(/^.*\s/, "").toUpperCase().trim(); // john
var first = fullname.replace(/\s.*$/, "").toUpperCase().trim(); // john
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YyCKx/
any ideas?

Comment: You can never split a name string accurately. You can never know how many first names, or last names or the order at which the user types them. If I had a name of "Fan Dong Ying" or "Lito De La Cerna", how would you know which is the first name and the last name? It would be best to have separate input boxes instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use split + shift methods.

```
var parts = "Thomas Mann".split(" "),
    first = parts.shift(),
    last = parts.shift() || "";
```

So in case of single word name it will give you expected result:

```
last = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

You'll need to change the line: splitFullName("firstName","lastName","fullName"); and make sure it includes the right field IDs from your form.

---

```
function splitFullName(a,b,c){
   String.prototype.capitalize = function(){
   return this.replace( /(^|\s)([a-z])/g , function(m,p1,p2){ return p1+p2.toUpperCase(); } );
  };
document.getElementById(c).oninput=function(){
    fullName = document.getElementById(c).value;
    if((fullName.match(/ /g) || []).length ===0 || fullName.substring(fullName.indexOf(" ")+1,fullName.length) === ""){
        first = fullName.capitalize();;
        last = "null";
    }else if(fullName.substring(0,fullName.indexOf(" ")).indexOf(".")>-1){
        first = fullName.substring(0,fullName.indexOf(" ")).capitalize() + " " + fullName.substring(fullName.indexOf(" ")+1,fullName.length).substring(0,fullName.substring(fullName.indexOf(" ")+1,fullName.length).indexOf(" ")).capitalize();
        last = fullName.substring(first.length +1,fullName.length).capitalize();
    }else{
        first = fullName.substring(0,fullName.indexOf(" ")).capitalize();
        last = fullName.substring(fullName.indexOf(" ")+1,fullName.length).capitalize();
    }
    document.getElementById(a).value = first;
    document.getElementById(b).value = last;
};
//Initial Values
if(document.getElementById(c).value.length === 0){
    first = document.getElementById(a).value.capitalize();
    last = document.getElementById(b).value.capitalize();
    fullName =  first + " " + last ;
    console.log(fullName);
    document.getElementById(c).value = fullName;}}

     //Replace the ID's below with your form's field ID's
     splitFullName("firstName","lastName","fullName");
```

---

Source: http://developers.marketo.com/blog/add-a-full-name-field-to-a-marketo-form/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` method

```
    var string = "ad";
var arr = string.split(" ");
var last = arr[0];
var first = arr[1];
if(first == null){
    first = "";
}
alert(last + "\n" + first)​;​
```

Answer (score 0):

If in every situation you have just "first last" you could use:

```
       var string = "john "
       var i = string.split(" ");
       alert("first: "+i[0]+ "\n"+ "last: " + i[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

var str='John';

var str2='Peter Smithon';

var str3='Peter';

var words=str.split(**/\s+/g**,2);

var first=words[0];

var last=words[1]||'';

alert(first+' '+last);

Comment: I rolled the edits to this answer back because the person who edited it left the `**` markup for bold in when they switched it over to being code formatted. By current standards this answer is missing an explanation, but given that it was answered in 2012 that may not apply in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this has already been replied to and marked as answered but i just want to note that if you do still want to use regex you can change the "last" expression:

```
var last = string.replace(/^[a-zA-Z]*/, "").toUpperCase().trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery( window ).load(function() {
            jQuery("#FullNametest").change(function(){
                var temp = jQuery(this).val();
                var fullname = temp.split(" ");
                var firsname='';
                var middlename='';
                var lastname = '';
                firstname=fullname[0];
                lastname=fullname[fullname.length-1];

                for(var i=1; i < fullname.length-1; i++) 
                {
                   middlename =  middlename +" "+ fullname[i];
                }
                jQuery('#FirstName').val(firstname);
                jQuery('#LastName').val(lastname);
            });
        });
```